# Can't get constructor from different class within same package to be recognized.

Tags: java, class-hierarchy

So these 2 files I am going to post are each in my DataBase package. The DBBinding class just needs to create an object with a string for the key and one for the value. Then the DBrecord is going to keep a collection of DBBindings that all have the same key string but diffrent value strings. For some reason I can not think/find the correct way to make a add method in DBrecord so that it calls the DBBinding class/objects constructor.

This is the method that is supposed to add the binding:

```
private void addRecord(String key_, String value_)
{
    //DBBinding myDBBinding=new DBBinding(key_, value_);//constructor not defined error
    //DBBinding myDBBinding(key_,value_);
    //DataBase.DBBinding myDBBinding=new DataBase.DBBinding(key_, value_);//constructor not defined error

}
```

Here's the DBBinding code followed by the DBrecord code.

```
package DataBase;

public class DBBinding {

    private String key;
    private String value;

    public void DBBinding(String key_, String value_)
    {
        String key =new String(key_);
        String value=new String(value_);
    }

    //public String toString()
    //{return key+": "+value;}

}
```

and

```
package DataBase;
//package DataBase.*;
import DataBase.*;//did not help ... ?

public class DBrecord {

    boolean select;
    String key;
    //need some type of collection to keep bindings. 

    public void DBrecord()
    {
        DBrecord myRecord=new DBrecord();
        select=false;
    }

    private void addRecord(String key_, String value_)
    {
        //DBBinding myDBBinding=new DBBinding(key_, value_);//constructor not defined error
        //DBBinding myDBBinding(key_,value_);
        //DataBase.DBBinding myDBBinding=new DataBase.DBBinding(key_, value_);//constructor not defined error

    }

    public String toString()
    {
        //out put key first then all values in collection/group/record. use correct formatting. 
    }



}
```

Comment: I realize this is just homework, but best practice would be to provide the DBBinding instance to the DBRecord class via a constructor parameter or using a setter method.  Used in conjunction with interfaces, you'll reduce the coupling between your classes, making them easier to test and maintain.  If you need the ability to create ephemeral objects within your methods, you'd typically provide a factory class that can be used via the same mechanisms.

Comment: Tvanfosson. Not quite sure what you mean by "provide the DBBinding instance to the DBRecord class via constructor" could you elaberate more on this and/or point me to some resources that discuss this.

Comment: The concept is called dependency injection, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In class `DBBinding` you must have `public DBBinding(String key_, String value_)`, the `void` makes the "constructor" actually to a method :-)

You have the same error in `DBrecord`.

By the way, don't do this:

```
String key =new String(key_);
```

Strings are immutable, nothing can happen if you "share" them. But your code forces Java to create a new object for an absolutely identical value. So use just

```
String key = key_;
```

However, in your case even this is wrong, as you create a new local variable `key` "shadowing" the class variable `key`. Look [here](http://blog.sanaulla.info/2008/06/27/shadowing-variables-in-java-demystified/) for an explanation.

So alltogether `DBBinding` should look like:

```
package DataBase;

public class DBBinding {

    private String key;
    private String value;

    public DBBinding(String key_, String value_)
    {
        key = key_;
        value =  value_;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want your code to work please remove the `void` construct from your constructors.

> Signature differences
>   Constructors and methods differ in three aspects of the signature: modifiers, return type, and name. Like methods, constructors can have any of the access modifiers: public, protected, private, or none (often called package or friendly). Unlike methods, constructors can take only access modifiers. Therefore, constructors cannot be abstract, final, native, static, or synchronized.
>
> The return types are very different too. Methods can have any valid
>   return type, or no return type, in which case the return type is given
>   as void. Constructors have no return type, not even void.

Comment: I agree with the main thrust of your answer, but technically it is wrong.  aaron burns does not have any voids on constructors because there are no explicitly defined constructors.  There are some poorly named methods that look like constructors.

Comment: Bogdan is correct that I have voids on my constructors. Emory may be right thought that my constructors are poorly written. What would you do differently about the constructors emory.